# get data attribute from “root” DOM node in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

Let’s say there is a `<div>` somewhere in HTML file:

I want to pass an attribute **data-person-name** from that `<div>` having id **root**,to react element

```
<div id="root" data-person-name="John"></div>
```

```
const element = <h1>Hello,{data-person-name}</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Please suggest the right way to do that.

Comment: Is this name supposed to change dynamically ?

Comment: Note that `personName` is an invalid attribute for `div` elements. If you want to add non-DOM information to elements, use a [`data-*` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) (e.g., `data-person-name`).

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking. You can get the element via `document.getElementById("root")` and get its attribute value via `getAttribute("attribute-name-goes-here")`. But this feels like an X/Y problem. *Why* do you want to take an attribute value and use it in a React element?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am rendering an input component on that Div, I have to send placeholder on basis of some condition, in `data-person-name`.So for that purpose, I need to do that

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Normally you wouldn't use attributes like that in React. You'd pass props through the hierarchy instead.

Comment: It's like I am just rendering a section using React, in the existing application, so there is a scenario in which I have to pass a placeholder from the existing app, I hope this helps you to understand the scenerio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cleaner way would be to prefix all custom attributes with "data-". Because there is no known attribute "personName" for a div element and having that is against W3 rules.
The code may look like this:

```
<div id="root" data-personName="John"></div>
const element = <h1>Hello,{document.getElementById('root').getAttribute('data-personName')}</h1>;
```

Comment: Thanks  @arm, it worked for me, but is there any other way for doing this.

Comment: if you want to pass personName by data attribute, I think there is no better way.
But you can use localStorage instead:
In App.js you can set personName: `localStorage.setItem('personName', 'John');`
and then use that value from anywhere: `localStorage.getItem('personName');`

Comment: Thanks @arm  for the solution